# Power BI publish to web on a password secured website

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I've been looking at options for sharing my Power BI reports with clients in a secure manner. By looking through the documentation and was looking into Power BI embedded, however, one of my colleagues suggested that instead of going through all of that we should simply publish the iFrame to a password protected website in our own site as to reduce the workload.

I was interested has anyone tried this and had any success? Are there any drawbacks to using this method? I'm fairly new in this field so I am afraid I am missing something.

Comment: There are several restrictions and limitations.  Have you read the manual?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a user account in your domain ClientName@yourdomain.com and share the reports/dashboards as per normal internal sharing?

To answer your question directly, I have done this before and it worked fine. 
Keep in mind that the iFrame is public so once the user has that user from the iFrame they would need to log into that page, they can go directly to the url within the iframe.

Comment: 2nd para doesn't make much sense, but I presume what you are trying to say is "once the user has the URL from the iFrame they would not need to log into that page".